# How to solve Problem with date method in the Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Have timestamp for the task in the MySQL - 1654423473. https://www.epochconverter.com/ correctly transforming this timestamp into the GMT: Sunday, 5 June 2022 г., 10:04:33. That is date of task creation. Using this Yii2 method I outputting this data in the view -

```php
public function getWasOnSite()
{
    $timePeriod = strtotime('now') - strtotime($this->dt_add);
    return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDuration($timePeriod);
}
```

And expecting some days, minutes, etc, but seeing this -1450 years, 11 months, 30 days, 17 hours, 3 minutes, 45 seconds ago

How to remake into the correct variant?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have unix timestamp in `$this->dt_add` then you shouldn't pass it into `strtotime()`. If you pass unix timestamp to that function it will return `false`.

Then if you do `strtotime('now') - false` the `false` is converted to 0 and you are left with current timestamp in `$timePeriod` instead of difference.
You should directly subtract `$this->dt_add` from current timestamp.

Also, you don't need to call `strtotime('now')` to get current timestamp. You can use `time()` function instead.

So, your whole code can look like this:

```php
public function getWasOnSite() 
{
    $timePeriod = time() - $this->dt_add;
    return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDuration($timePeriod);
}
```